Linear operator as linear combination of positive operators
Lemma: Let $V$ be vector space with inner product.

If $S\in L(V)$ is self adjoint, there exist positive linear operators $T, M\in L(V)$ such that $TM=MT=0$ and $S=T-M$.

If $V$ is a complex vector space, every linear operator $T\in L(V)$ is a linear combination of the form $T=T_1-T_2+iT_3-iT_4$, where $T_j$ are positive linear operators.


I have been able to prove 1. by using the spectral theorem ( I think this is the correct approach). However, I don't understand how to prove 2. Am I supposed to use 1. in order to prove 2. ?

Should the last part of 1. read "$S = T-M$?" and are the $T_i$ operators in 2. supposed to be positive?

Yes, sorry for the typo. Will correct it.


Am I supposed to use 1. in order to prove 2. ?

Yes. In fact, 1. is the hard part and 2. is the easy part. What you do, is write
$$
T=\frac{T+T^*}2+i\,\frac{T-T^*}{2i}
$$
and use part 1. on each of the two terms.
